# Run node server with PM2

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

How could I run `node server.js -p` by **pm2**?

Scripts of my `package.json` is like below,

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "start": "node server.js -p"
  },
```

When I execute `npm start` everything work truly. But I want to run this command with **pm2**.

To do it when I run `pm2 start npm -- start`, the process will add to the list of the **pm2** but my app not run!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the correct command is

```
pm2 start server.js
```

or if you want to pass `-p` to your app and a name

```
pm2 start server.js --name "my-server" -- -p
```